# writing a ruby gem that adds a js method to rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to write a ruby gem, when installed in a rails app, introduces the javascript method .foo()
So I will be able to do $(body).foo() or $(any-dom-element).foo()

How do I go about doing this?

So far what I've done:

Added this to my main rails app:

```
gem "foo", path: "~/foo"
```

Wrote the code for the foo() method

```
// file ~/foo/lib/assets/javascripts/foo.js
// https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/
$.fn.foo = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

//$( "a" ).foo(); // Makes all the links green.
```

Added a require statement in the main rails app

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require foo
```

Comment: http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/

Comment: Can you do it without a gem first? That's the hard part. Packaging in a gem is easy.

Comment: I did see update

Comment: Great. In this case, consult the "how do I create a gem" tutorials. This might do: https://www.sitepoint.com/create-ruby-gem-jquery-plugin-basics/

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured it out. Halfway through doing it, I found a great article about it.

instead of writing all the steps I did, I'm going to post a link to the  article which gives  step by step instructions

http://geekhmer.github.io/blog/2015/01/02/develop-your-own-gem-and-gemify-your-own-assets-using-rails-engine/